# VBA using Loop with .find and .copy values

Tags: vba, copy, paste

I want to use a loop in my SearchFunction in a way it will search for a customer till the right customer is found. I'm using a custom msgbox to define if the found customer is the customer i was looking for.

So basicly i want this:

```
MsgBox "Is this the customer you were looking for?"

Yes: it will copy cells(sheet2) and paste them into the invoice (sheet1)
No:  it will find next customer (and ask same question)**

** And keep doing/asking this till last found customer is shown.
```

This is how the msgbox looks like when a customer has been found:
[Custom msgbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1SEo.png)

At the moment it searches for a customer and shows it in a custom msgbox. When i say 'Yes this is the customer', it will copie the values like it should and paste them in the invoice. But when i say 'no this not my customer' it won't go to the next found customer but it will exit the SearchFunction.

I have tried using a Loop but i couldn't get it to work. Also i tried .findnext but i couldn't embed it to the code i'm using..

This is the code that i am using:

```
Sub SearchCustomer()
 '
 ' Search for customer
 '
 '*****************************************************************************************************


Dim Finalrow As Integer
Dim I As Integer
Dim cC As Object
Dim iR As Integer
Dim foundrange As Range

 '*****************************************************************************************************
 '                                      This Searches for the customer
 '*****************************************************************************************************

' Set up searchrange
    Set foundrange = Sheets("sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("B12").Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)

' Checks if fields are filled
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B12").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in a search key", vbOKOnly, "Search customer"

Else

    'When nothing is found
    If foundrange Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Customer not found," & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Refine your search key", vbOKOnly, "Search customer"

    Else

        Finalrow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1000").End(xlUp).Row

        For I = 2 To Finalrow

            'When range is found
            If Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 1) = foundrange Then
                Set cC = New clsMsgbox
                cC.Title = "Search contact"
                cC.Prompt = "Is this the customer you searched for?" & vbNewLine & "" & vbNewLine & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 1) & vbNewLine & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 2) _
                & vbNewLine & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 3) & vbNewLine & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 4) & vbNewLine & Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 5)
                cC.Icon = Question + DefaultButton2
                cC.ButtonText1 = "Yes"
                cC.ButtonText2 = "No"
                 iR = cC.MessageBox()

                If iR = Button1 Then
                    'Name
                    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 1).Copy
                    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B12").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                    'Adress
                    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 2).Copy
                    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B13").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                    'Zipcode & City
                    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 3).Copy
                    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B14").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                    'Phonenumber
                    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 4).Copy
                    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
                    'E-mail
                    Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(I, 5).Copy
                    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B16").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats

                ElseIf iR = Button2 Then
                    MsgBox "Customer not found", vbOKOnly, "Contact zoeken"

                End If

                Range("B12").Select

            End If 'gevonden item
        Next I

    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Some help would be great! Been searching for a long time now.

Thanks in advanced!

Greets Mikos

Comment: Please do not add "Solved" or "Fixed" to your title. There is a clear indication that your question has an accepted answer. See also meta discussion: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309266/2564301

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to restructure your code, the For loop doesn't make sense for looping over search results. You need a Do While Loop, see examples in [Range.FindNext Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196143.aspx)

Pseudo code:

```
Set foundrange = Sheets("sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=...)
Do While Not foundrange Is Nothing
    If Msgbox(<Customer data from foundrange.Row>) = vbYes Then 
        ' copy stuff
        Exit Do  ' we're done
    Else
        Set foundrange = Sheets("sheet2").Cells.FindNext(After:=foundrange)
    End If
Loop
```

P.S. *These are not the droids you're looking for!*

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply and advice! I will give it a go and post the code when i'm done!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Andre451 because he solved my problem!

Final code:

```
Sub SearchCustomer()
 '
 ' Search customer
 '
 '*****************************************************************************************************

    Dim Finalrow As Integer
    Dim foundrange As Range
    Dim answer As Integer

 '*****************************************************************************************************
 '                                      Search for customername
 '*****************************************************************************************************
' Search Range
Set foundrange = Sheets("sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=Sheets("sheet1").Range("B12").Value, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart)
Finalrow = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A:A").End(xlDown).Row

' Checks if search range is filled
If Sheets("sheet1").Range("B12").Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in a searchkey", vbOKOnly, "Search customer"
Else
    Do While Not foundrange Is Nothing
        If MsgBox("Is this the customer you were looking for? " & foundrange, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Zoek klant") = vbYes Then
            'Name
            foundrange.Copy
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B12").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            'Address
            foundrange.Offset(0, 1).Copy
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B13").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            'Zipcode and City
            foundrange.Offset(0, 2).Copy
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B14").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            'Phonenumber
            foundrange.Offset(0, 3).Copy
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            'Email
            foundrange.Offset(0, 4).Copy
            Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B16").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats
            Exit Do
        Else
            Set foundrange = Sheets("sheet2").Cells.FindNext(After:=foundrange)
            End If
Loop

Range("B12").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End If
End Sub
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Um, it is not very nice to un-accept my answer that solved your problem. (Only 1 answer can be the accepted one.)

Comment: Oow i'm sorry! Thought i could choose multiple answers as a result. Since the complete code was the answer because of you i thought it would be helpfull for others to see your advice used in a code. I'll change it right away!